# EditText hidden behind Keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am having an issue with EditText as when I entered lines more than it is being shown on the screen then EditText is hidden behind keyboard if I try to edit line which is below the visible area of EditText but If I edit any of those line which is in visible area it adjust the view for keyboard properly. I am not understanding what mistake I am doing?

I have used **adjustPan as softInputMode**.
Please have a look at this video to better understand what I want to say:

[EditTextIssueVideo](https://mega.nz/#!y0pQ1QLa!k0hiadHXH_O8-a9KyZ7zYDR0nuYVTTwTKw1PiMaVVhg)

EditText Code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/notes_et"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:hint="Notes"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:maxLines="5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/time_tp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.202" />
```

Comment: use `adjustResize` as `softInputMode`

Comment: adjustResize not working

Comment: Thanks to all for your suggestions, I got my solution. Actually it is a combination of "remove full screen" + adjustResize as softInputMode in manifest + "putting view container in scrollview"  + adding touch listener for edittext for inner scrolling due to child of scrollview. one more thing this view was in fragment and it also has bottom navigation menu.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because you have made your activity full screen. Try not making it full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Check your **AndroidManifest**  if you set

`android:windowSoftInputMode="|adjustResize|adjustPan"`

in any activity just remove it.

Comment: update your question with your **AndroidManifest** if its possible